# ANDROID - Undo and Redo in canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, undo-redo

I am drawing a circle (on touch) on bitmap to erase the overlay bitmap for that area in the circle.How do I add undo and redo functionality for this?

EDIT:Please refer [Android: Undo redo in CustomView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214443/android-undo-redo-in-customview) as it has the problem I'm currently facing with the given solution.

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        pcanvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, mPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }
```

onTouchEvent

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) 
    {
        switch (ev.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {

                x = (int) ev.getX();
                y = (int) ev.getY();
                invalidate();

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {

               x = (int) ev.getX();
                y = (int) ev.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;

            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                invalidate();
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You could probably keep a `Stack<Pair<Integer, Integer>>` to track the xy coordinate history. Then to undo, you just pop one. A similar thing can be used for redo, just remember to clear the redo stack once a touch adds a new pair to the undo stack. It would also be wise to limit the number of xy pairs you maintain in the stack to about 50.

Comment: @Kevin Could you help me with some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could keep Stacks to track the xy coordinate history.

Undo and Redo operations revolve around pushing and popping from the separate stacks.

*UndoCanvas*

```
public class UndoCanvas extends View {
    private final int MAX_STACK_SIZE = 50;
    private Stack<Pair<Float, Float>> undoStack = new Stack<>();
    private Stack<Pair<Float, Float>> redoStack = new Stack<>();

    private Bitmap originalBitmap;
    private Bitmap maskedBitmap;
    private Canvas originalCanvas;
    private Canvas maskedCanvas;
    private Paint paint;

    private float drawRadius;

    private StackListener listener;

    public UndoCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public UndoCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init();
    }

    public UndoCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        drawRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        paint = new Paint();
        // paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        paint.setAlpha(0);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.SOLID));
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            originalBitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true); // Copy of the original, because we will potentially make changes to this
            maskedBitmap = originalBitmap.copy(originalBitmap.getConfig(), true);
            originalCanvas = new Canvas(originalBitmap);
            maskedCanvas = new Canvas(maskedBitmap);
        } else {
            originalBitmap = null;
            originalCanvas = null;
            maskedBitmap = null;
            maskedCanvas = null;
        }

        int undoSize = undoStack.size();
        int redoSize = redoStack.size();

        undoStack.clear();
        redoStack.clear();

        invalidate();

        if (listener != null) {
            if (undoSize != undoStack.size()) {
                listener.onUndoStackChanged(undoSize, undoStack.size());
            }
            if (redoSize != redoStack.size()) {
                listener.onRedoStackChanged(redoSize, redoStack.size());
            }
        }
    }

    public StackListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public void setListener(StackListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                int undoSize = undoStack.size();
                int redoSize = redoStack.size();

                // Max stack size. Remove oldest item before adding new
                if (undoStack.size() == MAX_STACK_SIZE) {
                    // The undo history does not go further back, so make the change permanent by updating the original canvas/bitmap
                    Pair<Float, Float> pair = undoStack.remove(0);
                    maskPoint(originalCanvas, pair.first, pair.second);
                }

                undoStack.push(new Pair<>(ev.getX(), ev.getY()));
                redoStack.clear();
                invalidate();

                if (listener != null) {
                    if (undoSize != undoStack.size()) {
                        listener.onUndoStackChanged(undoSize, undoStack.size());
                    }
                    if (redoSize != redoStack.size()) {
                        listener.onRedoStackChanged(redoSize, redoStack.size());
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                int undoSize = undoStack.size();
                int redoSize = redoStack.size();

                // Max stack size. Remove oldest item before adding new
                if (undoStack.size() == MAX_STACK_SIZE) {
                    // The undo history does not go further back, so make the change permanent by updating the original canvas/bitmap
                    Pair<Float, Float> pair = undoStack.remove(0);
                    maskPoint(originalCanvas, pair.first, pair.second);
                }

                maskPoint(maskedCanvas, ev.getX(), ev.getY());
                undoStack.push(new Pair<>(ev.getX(), ev.getY()));
                redoStack.clear();
                invalidate();

                if (listener != null) {
                    if (undoSize != undoStack.size()) {
                        listener.onUndoStackChanged(undoSize, undoStack.size());
                    }
                    if (redoSize != redoStack.size()) {
                        listener.onRedoStackChanged(redoSize, redoStack.size());
                    }
                }
                break;

            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                invalidate();
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (maskedBitmap != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(maskedBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }

    public boolean undo() {
        if (!undoStack.empty()) {
            int undoSize = undoStack.size();
            int redoSize = redoStack.size();

            Pair<Float, Float> pair = undoStack.pop();
            // Redraw a single part of the original bitmap
            //unmaskPoint(maskedCanvas, pair.first, pair.second);

            // Redraw the original bitmap, along with all the points in the undo stack
            remaskCanvas(maskedCanvas);

            redoStack.push(pair); // Do not need to check for > 50 here, since redoStack can only contain what was in undoStack
            invalidate();

            if (listener != null) {
                if (undoSize != undoStack.size()) {
                    listener.onUndoStackChanged(undoSize, undoStack.size());
                }
                if (redoSize != redoStack.size()) {
                    listener.onRedoStackChanged(redoSize, redoStack.size());
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean redo() {
        if (!redoStack.empty()) {
            int undoSize = undoStack.size();
            int redoSize = redoStack.size();

            Pair<Float, Float> pair = redoStack.pop();
            maskPoint(maskedCanvas, pair.first, pair.second);
            undoStack.push(pair); // Do not need to check for > 50 here, since redoStack can only contain what was in undoStack
            invalidate();

            if (listener != null) {
                if (undoSize != undoStack.size()) {
                    listener.onUndoStackChanged(undoSize, undoStack.size());
                }
                if (redoSize != redoStack.size()) {
                    listener.onRedoStackChanged(redoSize, redoStack.size());
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void maskPoint(Canvas canvas, float x, float y) {
        if (canvas != null) {
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, drawRadius, paint);
        }
    }

    private void unmaskPoint(Canvas canvas, float x, float y) {
        if (canvas != null) {
            Path path = new Path();
            path.addCircle(x, y, drawRadius, Path.Direction.CW);

            canvas.save();
            canvas.clipPath(path);
            canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    private void remaskCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
        if (canvas != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());

            for (int i = 0; i < undoStack.size(); i++) {
                Pair<Float, Float> pair = undoStack.get(i);
                maskPoint(canvas, pair.first, pair.second);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface StackListener {
        void onUndoStackChanged(int previousSize, int newSize);

        void onRedoStackChanged(int previousSize, int newSize);
    }
}
```

You would want to limit the size of these stack so they don't overflow as a user drags across the screen. You can play around with the number, but 50 seems like a good start for me.

**EDIT**

As a side note, it might be good to redo / undo multiple entries at a time. Since `onTouchEvent` will trigger for very fine movements. Movements that the user would not notice when undo / redo are pressed.

**EDIT 2**

I have added to the above implementation, to handle the undo as well. I found that the strategy that only redraws at the specific point is insufficient as overlapping points are incorrect. (Point A and B overlap, removing B results in a subsection of A being cleared).

Because of this I remask the entire bitmap on an undo operation, this means that an intermediate bitmap is required for undoing. Without the intermediate bitmap, the undo operation will result in points no longer in the stack (50 max) from being removed as well. Since we do not support undo passed that point, using the original bitmap as the intermediate bitmap is sufficient.

Both methods are in the code so you can test both of them.

Lastly, I added a Listener to allow the Activity to know the state of the stacks. To Enable / Disable the buttons.

*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final UndoCanvas canvas = (UndoCanvas) findViewById(R.id.undoCanvas);
        final Button undoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUndo);
        final Button redoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRedo);
        undoButton.setEnabled(false);
        redoButton.setEnabled(false);

        canvas.setListener(new UndoCanvas.StackListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUndoStackChanged(int previousSize, int newSize) {
                undoButton.setEnabled(newSize > 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRedoStackChanged(int previousSize, int newSize) {
                redoButton.setEnabled(newSize > 0);
            }
        });

        undoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                canvas.undo();
            }
        });

        redoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                canvas.redo();
            }
        });

        canvas.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image));
    }
}
```

*Screenshots*

Before Undo

[image: Screen before undo operation(s)]

After Undo

[image: Screen after undo operation(s)]

Comment: The code does not restore the part of bitmap that is erased when i click undo.Could you see the question again to review the just added detail of the mPaint and pcanvas  and suggest where am i going wrong?

Comment: That wasn't in the original post. You could keep the original bitmap and draw it again before applying the mask. Or to improve performance, only draw the region affected (which would now be in the redoStack)

Comment: Hello kevin, i was unable to bring about the bitmap back after erasing and have also added a link in the question explaining my problem with the solution you provided. If you could help, it would be great.

Comment: @zek54 Hi Zek, I have created a view that should solve your problems. I have added a short explanation for the changes I've made.

Comment: Thanks a lot , kevin.